# The .gcda files not created when using gcov with cmake

Tags: cmake, gcov

I am using gcov with cmake. All the flags are set properly. .GCNO files are created properly. However, the situation is a little complex when executing the executables generated from the source files. The executables are run inside bash scripts.

Let me create a sample scenario so that you can give me accurate answer.

I have a file called MY_FILE.CC and its executable name is EXECUTABLE_FILE
I using cmake with all the flags set for gcov.
I have a script called THE_SCRIPT.SH, it is to be run with "make test". This script runs the EXECUTABLE_FILE file.

So the idea here is that the bash scripts (THE_SCRIPT.SH) in turn run the executable (EXECUTABLE_FILE) and running of these bash scripts do not create the .GCDA files. When I run the executable directly/manually, the .GCDA files are created. I believe the bash scripts are run inside sub shells and the parent shell is not able to know if the executable of the source was run or not. Can someone please confirm if this is exactly the situation? If not, then what is the exact problem? And if yes, then what could be the solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a working gcov-cmake integration here. If your gcda files are generated when you launch your prog directly, can you check the current working dir when launching your program in both cases ? When launched by the scripts, your exec may not have write rights on current working dir.

Comment: I am having a very very similar problem. I am trying to run unit tests via a CMake POST_BUILD custom command & collect coverage at the same time. The test script runs, and runs the test executable just fine, but no .gcda files are produced. I am confident that it is not a permissions issue, since the test-script is able to create files with the same name and location as the expected .gcda files using "touch" with no problem. There must be *something* about the environment that CMake uses to launch the test binary that gcov disagrees with ... but I am not sure *what* that might be.

Comment: Worth mentioning: running the test script outside of CMake produces the .gcda files with no problems; inside CMake however: no dice.

Comment: Also .gcda files are NOT produced when run under "make test" ... so it might be make rather than CMake...?

Comment: Have you tried executing the ``SCRIPT.SH`` file directly?

Comment: Running the script.sh file directly correctly produced the gcov files; but running it from "make test" did not -- even though the unit tests were executing correctly.

Comment: Somehow, after posting the above questions, I managed to do something to remedy the situation -- everything is now working just fine, but I am left a little bit concerned, because I do not understand why I was experiencing the symptoms that I described above. It is entirely possible that I was just doing something stupid, and my experiments to isolate the problem were not as "isolated" as I thought.

Answer (score 2):

May be this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089140/gcov-with-cmake-using-a-separate-build-directory)  is related to your problem.

Perhaps you could give more details on flags, directory structure of your project, etc.

Comment: I looked at that question before, sadly, it was not relevant. I am compiling with the correct flags (I can generate the .gcno & gcda files OK), and they do end up in the expected directories. I have an out-of-source build tree with a somewhat complex structure, but the files are ending up in the right place, and gcov & lcov are able to process them OK. As I mentioned before - I think that I was doing something stupid when I was testing things last week; perhaps inadvertently running some cleanup code, since I now have the system working as intended.

Comment: I will give you the bounty anyway, with thanks, since you have spent time on what was probably a wild goose chase.