# CMake produces object files with .obj extension instead of .o

Tags: c++, cmake, code-coverage, gcov, ninja

I am working in a new C++ project which is using CMake and Ninja to be built. 
I am new to both tools and was expecting to easily implement code coverage using gcov.

I was very fast and could compile my code with the flags ***-fprofile-arcs*** and ***-ftest-coverage***, and then link with the ***gcov*** library.

When executing the .exe file the *.gcda* files where generated as expected but when trying to generate the human readable coverage reports I realized that the gcov tool could not find the *.gcda* and *.gcno* files, even when they were there.

After some minutes I realized that the problem was that the objects files which are generated have the extension **.cpp.obj** instead of just **.o**, and the coverage files **.cpp.gcno** and **.cpp.gcda** instead of just **.gcno** and **.gcda** as gcov expects.

I have not found a way to tell cmake to "tell" ninja to give the extension **.o** to object files instead of **.cpp.obj**

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I was about to point out undocumented CMake's `CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE`, but I googled for it and it sounds like someone already struggled with your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40110752/5945883

Comment: Thanks for the fast and helpful answer! As the other question referenced by you, has a title which does not really point out the problem, I can imagine that it is difficult to find when you do not have a clue of the existence of CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE. For that reason, I will answer my own question with the solution that I used.

Comment: Well, to be honest, it is more about understanding that Ninja has nothing to do here. All it does it obey to CMake's generated commands. Once you know that you can google "CMake change object file extension". Then dig through old mailing lists, learn about magic `CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE` and google for it and find linked answer. Easy... ;) But the point was, the question could be improved by changing Ninja to CMake, as the solution can work with other generators as well.

Comment: you are right, I will reformulate the question.